In class P, does decidability implies searchability?
I'm studying a course on Intro to Computability, and I couldn't find an answer.
Often, we refer to problems in $\text{P}$ as problems that we can "efficiently search a solution for" (where efficiently stands for polynomial time).
What confuses me, is that the formal definition of the class $P$, only means a language $L \in \text{P}$ is decidable. Is it also possible to search for a witness efficiently?
The answer is simple in a case where we have a constructive polynomial time algorithm, but what about a more theoretical case?
Can it be proven that polynomial-time decidability implies polynomial-time searchability?

It seems like you are confusing the decision complexity class with the functional complexity class.

$P$ is a class of languages, or equivalently a class of decision problems. What is usually meant by statements like "problems in $P$ can be efficiently solved" is that there is an efficient (polynomial) algorithm that can tell us for any particular string $s$ whether it is a member of our language (or equivalently, whether our decision problem should output "yes" or "no"). Either way the "solution" is a single yes/no answer. What do you mean by search in this context? Searching for the yes/no answer? Searching for the algorithm that will give you the answer? Something else?

I guess you are alluding to the "decision vs search" problems.

Often, we refer to problems in   as problems that we can
"efficiently search a solution for" (where efficiently stands for
polynomial time).

This is not true (well, you correct yourself later...), the class $\text{P}$ is defined w.r.t to decision problems: a language $L$ is in $\text{P}$ if there is a deterministic  polynomial time algorithm that decides it in polynomial time, that is, given input $x$, the algorithm answers "yes" if $x\in L$, and answers "no" otherwise.

Is it also possible to search for a witness efficiently? The answer is
simple in a case where we have a constructive polynomial time
algorithm, but what about a more theoretical case? Can it be proven
that polynomial-time decidability implies polynomial-time
searchability?

In general decidability implies searchability, but that comes at a cost. For example, the answer here describes a naive way to turn a decision problem into a search problem. See also here, there are many examples of easy decision problems that have hard/open search problems.
If you wonder, however, whether we can turn a polynomial time decision problem into its corresponding search variant with only a polynomial blow-up in the runtime, then the answer is negative.   An example I have encountered recently is the problem of deciding wether a nondeterministic co-Büchi automaton on infinite words is good-for-games, or equivalently, the problem of deciding whether there is a finite-state strategy that witnesses that the nondeterministic choices of the automaton can be resolved based only on the past. Interestingly, deciding whether such a strategy exists is in $\text{P}$, yet we have an exponential lower-bound on its size (see here). So there is no hope to find such a strategy in polynomial time.

One counterexample is integer factorisation:
given an postive integer $n$, are there integers $a,b$ with $n>a>b>1$,
such that $n = a*b$.
the decision problem is in $P$ (primary test); but it is unknown, if the search problem, i.e. find $a$ and $b$, is in $P$
